# Google Cloud SQL Database Delete Protection

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I would like the ability to protect against the deletion of a cloud SQL instance. This seems like a good step to take to avoid actions from an angry employee or a regretful click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google added a deletion protection flag for Cloud SQL in August 2022.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/deletion-protection

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find anything like literally protecting the instance vs deletion, but, you could use the [predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/project-access-control#roles) in your instance to try to protect your instances from, as you said, angry employees.

For example:

- Keeping the role `owner` to yourself (assuming you are, indeed, the owner of this project).
- Depending on the needs of the employees, you can probably assign them the role `cloudsql.editor` or similar. If this is too much, you can create your own [custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role) to narrow down what you need.

As for a regretful click, there is no much you can do. You could regularly create an [export](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting) and save it on one of your buckets, just in case you need to create again your instance after a 'regretful' click.

Answer (score 0):

Well, terraform certainly seems to have added some kind of deletion protection on the GCP sql instance. When I try to "terraform destroy" , I get this error

```
Error: Error, failed to delete instance because deletion_protection is set to true. Set it to false to proceed with instance deletion
```

Perhaps this functionality was added after the OP had reported the issue - which is quite possible given how old this thread is.

A [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64611122/gcp-cloud-sql-failed-to-delete-instance-because-deletion-protection-is-set-to) which talks about this.