# GCP Cloud SQL failed to delete instance because `deletion_protection` is set to true

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql

I have a tf script for provisioning a Cloud SQL instance, along with a couple of dbs and an admin user. I have renamed the instance, hence a new instance was created but terraform is encountering issues when it comes to deleting the old one.

```
Error: Error, failed to delete instance because deletion_protection is set to true. Set it to false to proceed with instance deletion
```

I have tried setting the `deletion_protection` to `false` but I keep getting the same error. Is there a way to check which resources need to have the `deletion_protection` set to false in order to be deleted?
I have only added it to the `google_sql_database_instance` resource.

My tf script:

```
// Provision the Cloud SQL Instance
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "instance-master" {
  name             = "instance-db-${random_id.random_suffix_id.hex}"
  region           = var.region
  database_version = "POSTGRES_12"

  project = var.project_id

  settings {
    availability_type = "REGIONAL"
    tier              = "db-f1-micro"
    activation_policy = "ALWAYS"
    disk_type         = "PD_SSD"

    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled    = var.is_public ? true : false
      private_network = var.network_self_link
      require_ssl     = true

      dynamic "authorized_networks" {
        for_each = toset(var.is_public ? [1] : [])

        content {
          name  = "Public Internet"
          value = "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      }
    }

    backup_configuration {
      enabled = true
    }

    maintenance_window {
      day  = 2
      hour = 4

      update_track = "stable"
    }

    dynamic "database_flags" {
      iterator = flag
      for_each = var.database_flags

      content {
        name  = flag.key
        value = flag.value
      }
    }

    user_labels = var.default_labels
  }

  deletion_protection = false
  depends_on          = [google_service_networking_connection.cloudsql-peering-connection, google_project_service.enable-sqladmin-api]
}

// Provision the databases
resource "google_sql_database" "db" {
  name     = "orders-placement"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.instance-master.name
  project  = var.project_id
}

// Provision a super user
resource "google_sql_user" "admin-user" {
  name     = "admin-user"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.instance-master.name
  password = random_password.user-password.result
  project  = var.project_id
}

// Get latest CA certificate
locals {
  furthest_expiration_time = reverse(sort([for k, v in google_sql_database_instance.instance-master.server_ca_cert : v.expiration_time]))[0]
  latest_ca_cert           = [for v in google_sql_database_instance.instance-master.server_ca_cert : v.cert if v.expiration_time == local.furthest_expiration_time]
}

// Get SSL certificate
resource "google_sql_ssl_cert" "client_cert" {
  common_name = "instance-master-client"
  instance    = google_sql_database_instance.instance-master.name
}
```

Comment: Did you updated the old one with the `deletion_protection` to false?

Comment: which version of terraform are you using?
I found [this Github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/7677) where it is mentioned that this is solved on newer versions of terraform

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like your code going to recreate this sql-instance. But your current tfstate file contains an instance-code with `true` value for `deletion_protection` parameter. In this case, you need first of all change value of this parameter to `false` manually in tfstate file or by adding `deletion_protection = true` in the code with running `terraform apply` command after that (beware: your code shouldn't do a recreation of the instance). And after this manipulations, you can do anything with your SQL instance

Comment: deletion_protection = true is the default set by recent terraform versions if it is not defined in the apply step (at least for Google SQL). As such it needs to be set to disabled first before destroy works like Aron writes. An alternative is to go into the console and remove the instance there and then run terraform destroy again to proceed.

Comment: In `vi terraform.tfstate` locate `deletion_protection` and change it

Comment: @rsantiago, it's also can be used as a workaround way. But almost all manual changes in the `*.tfstate` file is dangerous

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set `deletion_protection=false`, apply it and then proceed to delete.

As per the documentation

> On newer versions of the provider, you must explicitly set deletion_protection=false (and run terraform apply to write the field to state) in order to destroy an instance. It is recommended to not set this field (or set it to true) until you're ready to destroy the instance and its databases.

[Link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance)

Editing Terraform state files directly / manually is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue and solved it in different way. I wanted to change bigquery table name but `deletion_protection` was not set to `false`. So i made two changes in terraform file:

1. Set `delete_protection` to `false`.
2. Change the bigquery table name.

After making the two changes in terraform file, `apply` command did not work as expected. The first change was not reflected while the `apply` command is executed. Actually `delete_protection` value was coming from state file that was the default value `true`. So i did the two things:

1. Set `delete_protection` to `false` and run `apply` command. Now `delete_protection` value is `false` in state file.
2. Change the table name and run `apply` command. Now updated value `delete_protection` attributed is applied.

Answer (score -1):

If you added `deletion_protection` to the `google_sql_database_instance`  after the database instance was created, you need to run `terraform apply` before running `terraform destroy` so that `deletion_protection` is set to false on the database instance.

Comment: this doesn't work as the deletion protection cannot be set to cloud SQL instances.